# NonlinearModelFit understanding

Tags: mathematical-optimization, education

I have a trouble with `NonlinearModelFit` questions.

**Question:** `V` is a function of `T` and `P`:

$$V(T,P)=T^{(3/2)}/(a+b P)$$

If `a` make a test with `T=300.` and `P = {0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}`, 
`V` value is happening `= {99.4,17.3,8.9,6.3,5.0,4.3,2.9,2.4,2.5,1.7,1.7}`.

Using this data, you will find the `a` and `b` constants of *Mathematica*'s `NonlinearModelFit` by using the above `V` function.

My wrong solution is

```
Equation = T^(3/2)/(a + b P)
data = Table[{P, T, Equation}, {P, 0, 100, 10}, {T, 300, 300, 10}]
NonlinearModelFit[data, Equation, {a, b}, x]
```

But answer is

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you in an exam right now?

Comment: So you have lots of time to go through the documentation and try to do it yourself. When you encounter issues, show the codes you'll get and specify which part you have problems with. As it stands now, this is a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this community is no do-my-homework-for-me service and the OP should know better than to ask for the answers to his exam questions online.

Comment: Thank you all of you. İt is not online exam or homework. Nowadays I am working final exam. I have to learn nonlinearmodelfit. But I did not understand. Lecturer does not teach of them . But he will ask on the exam... Anyway As you say We will go to step by step. I edited my question and I have shown my answer. Thank you your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, let it be. But it's your task to go through the documentation and figure out what's going on:

```
P = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100};
V = {99.4, 17.3, 8.9, 6.3, 5.0, 4.3, 2.9, 2.4, 2.5, 1.7, 1.7};
T = 300.;

data = Transpose[{P, V}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, T^(3/2)/(a + b p), {a, b}, p]
```

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Medium]}], Plot[Normal[nlm], {p, 0, 100}]]
```

[image]

```
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image]

```
nlm["RSquared"]
```

> 0.999891

Comment: Thank you very much corey. You saved my life.